# How to solve error HE0004: Could not load the framework 'ContentDeliveryServices' in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: ios, xamarin, visual-studio-2022

I have Visual Studio 17.5.3 installed on my PC with iOS version Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK 16.2.0.5.

I am connected to a Mac that is running Ventura 13.3.1 with XCode 14.3.

When I attempt to deploy from Visual Studio on the PC, I get the following error:

error HE0004: Could not load the framework 'ContentDeliveryServices' (path: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/ContentDeliveryServices.framework/ContentDeliveryServices):

I believe this has to do with Visual Studio not being compatible with XCode 14.3 because I upgraded my Mac and this problem started happening, but I haven't yet out if this is 14.2 because the installation takes a long time.

I will be trying to install 14.2 to see if it solves it, but in the meantime (and for future readers) does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Note that HE0004 error does appear in other posts online, but I haven't yet found any that mention this specific file. They seem to mention `DVTITunesSoftwareServiceFoundation`, and the solution there has been to downgrade XCode as well.

Comment: Same problem, Does anyone know how to solve?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can install the package

[Xamarin.iOS 16.4.0.3.pkg](https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/60490eec-956e-47b3-b063-79cadfe6ef11/b9c977eb4bc99a72f1deed54a680bd67/xamarin.ios-16.4.0.3.pkg)

To overwrite your Xamarin.iOs installation, and keep working with Xcode 14.3

Doing this worked for me!

Comment: Note that the .pkg is a Mac file, not PC, so be sure to download/double click it there. Also, you can track progress on this issue here: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/17561

Comment: Additionally, if you do install Xamarin.iOS 16.4.0.3 on your Mac and attempt to debug from Visual Studio 2022 on PC, you will receive a warning that the versions on PC and Mac do not match. You should not downgrade the installation on the Mac as this will once-again cause the problems explained in the original questions. It seems as if the mismatch is okay.

Comment: Led Machine, glad to see this here. Where can we found all the pre-release of Xamarin.iOS? Xamarin.Android too?

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot @LedMachine where did you find that pkg?

Comment: This did the trick. Also, updating Visual Studio 2022 to version 17.5.4. did NOT fix the problem. As of today's date, Visual Studio is still behind. One of the things that's bothered me most about Xamarin development (whether in Xamarin Forms, Uno Platform, or now MAUI) is the need to keep the Mac installs in sync with the Windows installs... serious pain in the butt. Thanks for the fix, Led Machine.

Comment: fixed it also for me tks!

Comment: According to the Github issue the correct 'fix' (i.e. workaround) is to uninstall XCode 14.3 and install XCode 14.2 on your Mac: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/17561

This will eliminate the annoyance of having this issue recur frequently, and having to install the above referenced Xamarin.iOS pkg on your Mac.

Comment: I think this compatible build for Xcode 14.3 was provided as part of this GitHub thread : https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/17561#issue-1588218177